# meteor 1.3 with npm line by line

Tags: node.js, meteor, npm

Below is the template for 'line-by-line' with node js. How is 
this changed to work with server side meteor 1.3  that supports npm now ?

```
         var LineByLineReader = require('line-by-line'),
         lr = new LineByLineReader('big_file.txt');

         lr.on('error', function (err) {
      // 'err' contains error object
          });

          lr.on('line', function (line) {

          });
```

Comment: use Meteor.bindEnvironment to replace 'function' in the callbacks ?

Answer (score 0):

```
    `var future = new Future();

    lr = new LineByLineReader('/home/mark/big_file.txt');

     console.log("got new line reader");

   lr.on('error',Meteor.bindEnvironment(function (err) {
    // 'err' contains error object
   }));

   lr.on('line', Meteor.bindEnvironment(function (line) {
    // 'line' contains the current line without the trailing newline        character.

         console.log("got line " + line);
}));


   lr.on('end', Meteor.bindEnvironment(function () {
// All lines are read, file is closed now.
    console.log("NOW DONE");
    future.return("hello joe");
 }));


     var requestResults = future.wait();

  }
```

Comment: oops  return future.wait();